# CSS Image size wont change

Tags: html, css

Hey guys so my problem is quite simple just I am not sure how to fix it.

I am basically trying to scale this image to fit the div width but it aint working for some reason. Width and height will keep their original size for some reason..

```
<body>
        <div id="header"> 
            <div>
                <ul id="mymenu">
                    <li><a href="text">homepage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="text">blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="text">photos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="text">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="text">links</a></li>
                    <li><a href="text">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div id="bgfix"> <!-- here is the image -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Thats the HTML of it, it should take mymenu size and make the picture be its 100% width.

CSS code

```
#bgfix {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: url("../img/home_bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
#bgfix {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: url("../img/home_bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

This will make the background image the full width of its parent and adjust the height automatically to keep the correct proportions of the image. Alternatively, you can use `background-size: cover`, which will fill the container, but cut off some of the image, or `background-size: contain;`, which will scale the image to fit into the container, but leave a little bit of space. In all cases you might want to add `background-position: center center;` to center the image both vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Thanks but I have 1 more problem when I do this, I want so nothing can be placed on the div. In my case, if I place any text in a different div bellow the image it will appear either on the image or above it

Answer (score 2):

The background image of a div doesn't automatically scale to cover the whole div.

If you want the background to scale you can add `background-size:cover;` or `background-size:contain;` (depending on how you want it to look like).

Read more on this property here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: Honestly, that div will be empty, I just need to set image to no repeat and resize it properly, I seen that only the bg image can have the no repeat, is there any way that I can do this without the div but still keep the no-repeat with for example <img>

Comment: The <img> tag doesn't repeat anything, it just displays the image once. To make it the same size as the containing div add `width:100%;height:100%`. You'll also want to set a z-index to make it a background. Check this fiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/jq3qfqot/1/

Comment: Hmm yeah works with img tag altho there is 1 more problem, basically the text or anything I put bellow it wont appear correctly. It will appear on the picture
http://pastebin.com/B4s5cUMv